# filter a json array (which has million items) based on search criteria

Tags: java, json, search, filter

I am at loss of finding the best way to filter a json array (which has million items) based on some search criteria which keeps on changning.

eg: find all items based on region_id and pool_id

The json array format as below

```
[
    {
        "url": "webservices/rest/resources/1/", 
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "con A", 
        "is_parent": 1, 
        "account_id": 1, 
        "pool_id": 4, 
        "region_id": 5, 
        "market_id": 1, 
        "baseline_type": "Type 1", 
        "is_producer": 0, 
        "utilisation_type": 0, 
        "forecasting_algorithm": "Clipped nominal capacity", 
        "availability_protocol": null, 
        "communication_protocol": "OPC", 
        "activation_protocol": [
            " Demo"
        ], 
        "installed_capacity": 2000.0, 
        "nominal_capacity": 1000.0, 
        "positive_tolerance": 300.0, 
        "negative_tolerance": 300.0, 
        "capacity_fee": 20.0, 
        "energy_fee": 20.0, 
        "activation_fee": 10.0, 
        "parent_resource": null
    }, 
    {
        "url": "webservices/rest/resources/2/", 
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "con B", 
        "is_parent": 1, 
        "account_id": 2, 
        "pool_id": 1, 
        "region_id": 4, 
        "market_id": 1, 
        "baseline_type": "Type 1 DW", 
        "is_producer": 1, 
        "utilisation_type": 0, 
        "forecasting_algorithm": "Clipped nominal capacity", 
        "availability_protocol": null, 
        "communication_protocol": " Demo", 
        "activation_protocol": [
            " Demo"
        ], 
        "installed_capacity": 3000.0, 
        "nominal_capacity": 1000.0, 
        "positive_tolerance": 300.0, 
        "negative_tolerance": 300.0, 
        "capacity_fee": 20.0, 
        "energy_fee": 20.0, 
        "activation_fee": 10.0, 
        "parent_resource": null
    },
.
.
. // million items

]
```

I tried using the following api's in java

- Jackson api for converting the json to java objects.
- Google Guava api for filtering java objects.

Is it the best procedure to filter the json data? If not, please advice.

Comment: There is no best procedure. Did you succeed? Anything wrong with your solution?

Comment: Where is the array coming from? Can do the filtering in some database call that givies you these objects? Because letting clients make querys and filter on any of the fields/columns is pretty much what datases do.

Comment: @SreeYReddy if it works and meets your requirements it is the best solution ;). IMO, you should hunt around for other solutions only if you need to optimise either for speed or memory.

Comment: @ dotvav - I am able to achieve. It is working perfectly.  Here I am converting the JSON into java objects and then filtering the objects using Guava library. I think converting all JSON  items of array to JAVA objects and keeping these objects in memory, is not a good approach. My concern, is there any better solution apart from it.

Comment: @Simon : Its coming from external system on which I don't have control.